# Instance member 'nowShowing' cannot be used on type 'Link' err while defining constant globally

Tags: swift

I am trying to create some global constant but when I try to use them in my class I get this error.

This my constant class:

```
import Foundation

struct Link {
   static let nowShowing: String = "http://172.20.10.3:8888/smartcinemaz/movie_details.json"
   static let comingSoon: String = "http://172.20.10.3:8888/smartcinemaz/coming_soon.json"
}
```

and here I am using it:

```
let url = URL(string: Link.nowShowing)
```

Comment: I just copied your code into a Swift playground and I do not get any errors.

Comment: i am also wondering what is the issue then

Comment: try restarting xcode